# Haskell: Parsing a file with Parsec and IO

Tags: haskell, io, parsec

So I'm still trying to get comfortable using Parsec, but I'm slowly working it into my toolbox.

When I have a file I need to parse, I find myself reading the file in as a string, and then passing the contents to parsec:

```
problem <- readFile input                               
case runParser myParser () input problem of
  Left err  -> hPutStrLn stderr $ "Error: " ++ show err 
  Right cs  -> -- continue processing...
```

This seems like a fairly common pattern though - is there some existing function that I can use that takes a `ParsecT String u IO a` and a `FilePath` and parses the contents?  I can't find anything in hoogle, but that might just be a failure of imagination.

Comment: There's `parseFromFile` in `Text.Parsec.String` or `Text.Parsec.ByteString`, but they only work with pure parsers (e.g. `ParsecT String () Identity a`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not `ParsecT`, but there's [`parseFromFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-String.html)`:: Parser a -> String -> IO (Either ParseError a)`. However, if your code snippet is accurate, you don't actually need the `IO` in your parser, so this shouldn't be a problem. Something like this should produce the behaviour you want:

```
import Text.Parsec.String
import System.Exit
import System.IO

parse :: Parser a -> String -> IO a
parse p fileName = parseFromFile p fileName >>= either report return
  where
    report err = do
        hPutStrLn stderr $ "Error: " ++ show err
        exitFailure
```

It's still a little verbose, but you can define `report` somewhere common and use it throughout your program; then `parse` is a one-liner.